# Duplicating rows with certain value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to duplicate rows that have a certain value in a column and replace the value with another value.

For instance, I have this data:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 2], 'C': ['A','B','C','D']})
```

Now, I want to duplicate the rows that have 2 in column 'B' then change 2 to 4

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4], 'C': ['A','B','B','C','D','D']})
```

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `append`, to append the rows where `B == 2`, which you can extract using `loc`, but also reassigning `B` to `4` using `assign`. If order matters, you can then order by `C` (to reproduce your desired frame):

```
>>> df.append(df[df.B.eq(2)].assign(B=4)).sort_values('C')
   B  C  Date
0  1  A     1
1  2  B     2
1  4  B     2
2  3  C     3
3  2  D     4
3  4  D     4
```

Comment: Thanks, but because my column name has space, it arose the syntax error. 
let say the column name is "patient name," then df.patien name does not work. :((

Comment: If there are spaces in the column name you can also use `df['patient name']`